# Tengo problemas al ejecutar sentencias de SQL

Tags: sql

tengo las siguientes dudas, estoy haciendo unos ejercicios, es de un cuestionario de 25 preguntas sobre SQL, pero me apoyarían mucho, solo me faltan estos y mas que otra cosa me encantaría una explicación porque soy nuevo y quiero aprender.

Aquí diseñe una tabla (la estructura);

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido_paterno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido_materno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `compania` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pedidos` int(10) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

y debo contestar lo siguiente:

1. Crea una vista que contenga dos columnas, nombre de la compañía del cliente y número de pedidos realizados. Deben aparecer todos los clientes, si no ha realizado ningún pedido, que muestre 0 en pedidos realizados y mostrar por cantidad de pedidos realizados.

Hasta el momento llevo este código, pero solo muestra el primer resultado de mi tabla y no me ordena nada, les agradeceria su apoyo.

```
CREATE VIEW vista_pedidos AS SELECT clientes.compania, pedidos FROM clientes ORDER BY COUNT(pedidos) ASC
```

Comment: Por favor, explica el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Tu enunciado suena a una pregunta basada en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de [cierre](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta y mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Listo, perdón, estás en toda la razón, ya la cambié y espero haber sido claro, la verdad me esta costando un poco de trabajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu primera pregunta puede ser respondida con un where, cuya función es filtrar todos los productos de acuerdo a una categoría especifica.

```
SELECT * FROM Productos
WHERE Categoría ='NombredeAlgunaCategoria';
```

Tu segunda pregunta se puede resolver con un where que tiene dos condiciones, donde la primera filtra la los últimos 15 días de ventas y la segunda condición verifica que el inventario sea mayor o igual al nivel de repedido.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Productos
WHERE fecha_pedido BETWEEN
  '2014-05-16' and '2014-05-01'
AND 
  Stack >= Nivel_repedido
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha resuelto las primeras dos dudas que tengo, no habia pensado en usar Between, hice pruebas y si funcionó, estuve tratando de utilizar NOW(), para que las fechas fueran dinámicas, me resultó lo siguiente:

SELECT * FROM productos WHERE datediff(NOW(),fecha_pedido)<=15 AND stack >= nivel_repedido

Comment: En donde si estoy super atorado es en esta parte, no tengo ni idea.

Aquí te pido que tu diseñas una tabla (la estructura) y que contestes lo siguiente:

->Crea una vista que contenga dos columnas, nombre de la compañía del cliente y número de pedidos realizados. Deben aparecer todos los clientes, si no ha realizado ningún pedido, que muestre 0 en pedidos realizados. Mostrar por cantidad de pedidos realizados.